# javascript querySelector on the response variable from a jQuery $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html2canvas

I'm developing a system using Bootstrap and I'm having trouble printing some tables. The background colors are not showing as they appear on the screen.

I finally found a solution for my problem with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

I can simply querySelect an element on my html and html2canvas will "draw" it on a canvas and it will print exactly as it appears on the screen.

To do that used the code below:

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

My question is: can I use querySelector with the response variable that I get from a jQuery $.ajax call?

I tried to do this in many ways and it never worked out. Here's an example:

```js
$.ajax({
url: 'url',
type: 'POST',
success: function (data) {
 html2canvas($(data).querySelector("#selector")).then(canvas => {
  let wnd = window.open("about:blank", "");
  wnd.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 });
}
});
```

Andy idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What is `data`? Is it a DOM node? I doubt it, so you need to make it one.

Comment: data is a string with html code in it... how can I make it a DOM node?

Comment: jquery collections don't have a .querySelector method... They do have a similar method, `.find`, but even then it will only work if the element you are looking for is a child of a root node. If the root node is the target, you don't need `.find` at all.

Answer (score -1):

`data` is probably a `String` containing HTML. If you want to work with it in the DOM you'll need to parse it into DOMNodes first. You can do this by inserting the string as the innerHTML of another element, using the `DOMParser`, or jQuery's `$.parseHTML`. I used the first in the code below.

```js
$.ajax({
url: 'url',
type: 'POST',
success: function (data) {
  var template = document.createElement('template');//you could elements other than <template>
  template.innerHTML = data;//parses the html string into DOM Nodes
 html2canvas(template.content.querySelector("#selector")).then(canvas => {
  let wnd = window.open("about:blank", "");
  wnd.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 });
}
});
```

Caveat, I don't know html2canvas and it might need the element to be inserted into the page... but I wouldn't think so.

*EDIT*

As an example of retrieving the parsed DOM elements:

```js
var htmlString = "<div id='new_div'><p id='new_p'>New Element</p></div>";

var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = htmlString;
//DOMNodes are parsed, but not attached to the document
console.log('new DOMNodes are "floating" in memory, dont exist in document');
console.log(document.querySelector('#new_div'));
console.log('should find the element in the template, which is not attached to the document');
console.log(template.content.querySelector('#new_div'));

document.body.appendChild(template.content);
console.log('attached nodes to the body. they should be findable on document now');
console.log(document.querySelector('#new_div'));

//via jquery
var newStuff = $.parseHTML(htmlString);//returns an array-like?
var actualNewDiv = newStuff[0];
console.log('jquery parsed reference to the DOMNodes');
console.log(actualNewDiv);//could be passed to html2canvas without querySelector-ing
console.log('since the root element IS the div, we cant query for it');
console.log(actualNewDiv.querySelector('#new_div'));
console.log('we CAN querySelect the p, because it is a child');
console.log(actualNewDiv.querySelector('#new_p'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After transformed into DOM Nodes, the querySelector on the template always returns null. Even if I query "template" or "html" or "body" for example

Comment: what are you querySelecting _on_? Unless you append it to the document you won't be able to `document.querySelector...` which is why i have the query selector attached to the template element I created

Comment: I didn't know you had to add a .content. I was doing template.querySelector. It all worked out. Thank you very much for your help... or as we say here in Brazil... Obrigado!